# How does WordPress generate URL slugs?

Tags: urls, slug

Is there a page somewhere that details exactly how WordPress generates slugs for URLs? I'm writing a script that needs to generate URL slugs identical to the ones WordPress generates.

Comment: The answers to this question are now outdated - use https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_unique_post_slug instead.

Comment: @SinisterBeard Came across this by chance today. You would have been very welcome to either add a new answer or to edit the accepted one. Will update it now. Better late than never. Thanks for making a valid point.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As per [@SinisterBeard](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/63673/sinisterbeard)'s very valid comment to the question already a couple of years back now, this answer has long been outdated and the mentioned function(s) hence been replaced by a newer API:

**See [`wp_unique_post_slug`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_unique_post_slug/).**

**Original Answer**

Off the bat, I can't give you a page/tutorial/documentation on how WP slugs are generated, but take a look at the [`sanitize_title()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_title) function.

Don't get a wrong impression by the function name, it is *not* meant to sanitize a title *for further usage as a page/post title*. It takes a title string and returns it to be used in a URL:

- strips HTML & PHP
- strips special chars
- converts all characters to lowercaps
- replaces whitespaces, underscores and periods by hyphens/dashes
- reduces multiple consecutive dashes to one

There *might* be edge cases where the core does something additional (you'd have to look at the source to verify that `sanitize_title()` will *always* suffice in generating *exactly* the same you expect), but this should cover at least 99%, if not all, cases.

Comment: @kaiser: I figured you're simply in love with *T5 Rewrite* :) (which is on my agenda to check out) | and generally: If a title is really long, WP also trims slugs to a certain maximum length. That's one of those cases where I am not entirely sure whether that's done by the `sanitize_title` filter applied in the function as well, or whether that's handled by something else after the function has run.

Comment: I guess it's the `sanitize_title`-filter that one needs to check out. But there're also other [related functions](http://queryposts.com/?s=sanitize_title). I really got no idea about this. Sometimes it seems `SimplePie` is easier to understand than the `WP_Rewrite` thing. Btw: Toscho works on integrating the "Monkeyman Rewrite Analyzer"-functionality into his plugin. That's where things start to really get interesting.

Comment: Also consider [sanitize_title_with_dashes()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_title_with_dashes) if you want to be a little more explicit about generating a URL-friendly slug.

Answer (score 7):

You can use this function:

```
static public function slugify($text)
{
  // replace non letter or digits by -
  $text = preg_replace('~[^\pL\d]+~u', '-', $text);

  // transliterate
  $text = iconv('utf-8', 'us-ascii//TRANSLIT', $text);

  // remove unwanted characters
  $text = preg_replace('~[^-\w]+~', '', $text);

  // trim
  $text = trim($text, '-');

  // remove duplicate -
  $text = preg_replace('~-+~', '-', $text);

  // lowercase
  $text = strtolower($text);

  if (empty($text)) {
    return 'n-a';
  }

  return $text;
}
```

Its kind of exactly how the wp url sanitize function works.

Comment: Came across this by chance today. You say, "Its kind of exactly how the wp url sanitize function works." Then, given that one *is* already in the context of php execution hooked into some WordPress either from a theme- or plugin-based call chain, **For what thinkable reason would one not simply use one of the relevant functions of the native `sanitize*` API? *Already available as a free function in the global namespace*, for better or for worse. Why recommend adding an additional 503 bytes to the ~source~ distribution code that duplicate existing functionality?** Just because it's possible?

Comment: @JohannesPille in my understanding, the OP wanted to have a `slug` generator _outside_ of WP, but still making sure that his generated slugs would be WP-compatible. While it's true that this functionality already exists in the WP code, nevertheless, to _use_ it _outside_ WordPress, it would mean basically including _almost all_ the WP code — which is substantially more than 503 bytes of code :)

Answer (score 4):

### Core at your service

There's no *developer mode* built into WordPress aside from `WP_DEBUG`, which doesn't help you too much in this case. Basically WP uses the ["Rewrite API"](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API), which is a function based, low level wrapper for the [`WP_Rewrite` class, which you can read about in Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Rewrite). The `global $wp_rewrite` object stands at your service to inspect it or interact with the class.

### Plugins that help looking into it.

[Toschos "T5 Rewrite"-Plugin](https://github.com/toscho/t5-rewrite) and [Jan Fabrys "Monkeyman Rewrite Analyzer"-Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/) will guide you your way. I've written a small extension for "T5 Rewrite" to smoothly integrate it with the "Monkeyman Rewrite Analyzer", which you can find in the "T5 Rewrite" repos wikie [here on GitHub](https://github.com/toscho/t5-rewrite/wiki/MonkeyMan-Rewrite-Analyzer-Extension).

The "Monkeyman"-plugin adds a new page, filed in the admin UI menu under *Tools*. The "T5 Rewrite"-plugin adds a new help tab to the *Settings* > *Permalinks* page. My extension adds the help tabs to the mentioned *Tools*-page too.

Here's a screenshot of what the "T5 Rewrite"-plugins help tab content looks like.

[image]

<sup>Vorlage = Pattern | Beschreibung = Explanation | Beispiele = Examples</sup>

### Notes

The "T5 Rewrite"-plugin does a wonderful job with helping you inspect the rewrite object. And it does even more: It adds new possibilities. Therefore it's (at least in my installations) part of my basic plugins package.

Answer (score 3):

Forgive for resuming an old question, but I had the same necessity as found out this method works perfectly for me:

```
$some_string = "DON'T STOP ME NOW!";
$slug = sanitize_title(sanitize_title($some_string, '', 'save'), '', 'query');
echo $slug; // dont-stop-me-now
```

This method uses a double sanitization.

The first one uses the `save` mode, where HTML and PHP tags are stripped, and  accents are removed (accented characters are replaced with non-accented equivalents).

The second `query` mode ensures all spaces are replaced with dashes `-` and other punctuation removed.

Hope this helps someone! :)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, if you look core function wp_insert_post (post.php), you will see that it does the following:

```
$data['post_name'] = wp_unique_post_slug( sanitize_title( $data['post_title'], $post_ID ), $post_ID, $data['post_status'], $post_type, $post_parent );

$wpdb->update( $wpdb->posts, array( 'post_name' => $data['post_name'] ), $where );
```

The key thing to note is that uses both wp_unique_post_slug and sanitize_title:

```
wp_unique_post_slug( sanitize_title(
```